# Is there a way to get the current ref count of an object in Python?

Tags: python, refcounting

Is there a way to get the current ref count of an object in Python?

Answer (score 150):

According to the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount), the `sys` module contains a function:

```
import sys
sys.getrefcount(object) #-- Returns the reference count of the object.
```

Generally 1 higher than you might expect, because of object arg temp reference.

Comment: Link to the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount

Comment: To explain the "1 higher" comment, calling a function creates a temporary reference to the variable used as the parameter.

Answer (score 83):

Using the `gc` module, the interface to the garbage collector guts, you can call `gc.get_referrers(foo)` to get a list of everything referring to `foo`.

Hence, `len(gc.get_referrers(foo))` will give you the length of that list: the number of referrers, which is what you're after.

See also the [`gc` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html).

Comment: It should also be mentioned the count will be +1, since the gc list refers to the object, too.

Comment: I think @Dan that the answer is correct:


    >>> import gc
    >>> class Bar():
    ...     pass
    ... 
    >>> b = Bar()
    >>> len(gc.get_referrers(b))
    1
    >>> gc.get_referrers(b)
    [{'b': <__main__.Bar instance at 0x7f1f010d0e18>, 'Bar': <class __main__.Bar at 0x7f1f010d6530>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'gc': <module 'gc' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}]

Comment: @tehvan's answer (`sys.getrefcount(object)`) is more straightforward than `len(gc.get_referrers(foo))`, if you really only need the number.

Comment: in Android's qpython3, it gives wrong answer. every time.

Answer (score 13):

There is `gc.get_referrers()` and `sys.getrefcount()`. But, It is kind of hard to see how `sys.getrefcount(X)` could serve the purpose of traditional reference counting. Consider:

```
import sys

def function(X):
    sub_function(X)

def sub_function(X):
    sub_sub_function(X)

def sub_sub_function(X):
    print sys.getrefcount(X)
```

Then `function(SomeObject)` delivers '7', 
`sub_function(SomeObject)` delivers '5', 
`sub_sub_function(SomeObject)` delivers '3', and 
`sys.getrefcount(SomeObject)` delivers '2'.

In other words: If you use `sys.getrefcount()` you must be aware of the function call depth. For `gc.get_referrers()` one might have to filter the list of referrers.

I would propose to do **manual reference counting** for purposes such as “isolation on change”, i.e. “clone if referenced elsewhere”.

Answer (score 9):

```py
import ctypes

my_var = 'hello python'
my_var_address = id(my_var)

ctypes.c_long.from_address(my_var_address).value
```

`ctypes` takes address of the variable as an argument.
The advantage of using `ctypes` over `sys.getRefCount` is that you need not subtract 1 from the result.

Comment: While funny this method should not be used: 1) nobody will understand what is going on while reading the code 2) it depends on implementation details of CPython: id being the address of the object and the exact memory  layout of a PyObject. Just substract 1 from getrefcount() if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Every object in Python has a reference count and a pointer to a type.
We can get the current reference count of an object with the **sys module**. You can use **sys.getrefcount(object)**, **but keep in mind that passing in the object to getrefcount() increases the reference count by 1**.

```
import sys

name = "Steve"

# 2 references, 1 from the name variable and 1 from getrefcount
sys.getrefcount(name)
```

Comment: Works for string values but for numeric values returns a weird long number 1000000011. Why?

Comment: @noob7 small numbers (`range(-5,257)`) are shared objects, which will never be released from memory and same numbers are the same object. It seems it is done by adding a big number to refcount. Adding big number can be safer if third-party C extension accidentally release one of them, and it is very clear it is actually kept.