# Still confused about reference counting

Tags: python, reference, counting

Out of curiosity, I am trying to understand how reference counting works in Python. These two entries:

- [Why are Python Ref Counts to small integers surprisingly high?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38253757/3001761)
- [Is there a way to get the current ref count of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510406/3001761)

were helpful, but still raised questions.

1. Using `sys.getrefcount()` returns a different value than `len(gc.get_referrers())`.  For example:

   ```
   >>> a = 3
   >>> print sys.getrefcount(a)
   38
   >>> print len(gc.get_referrers(a))
   23
   ```

   Why the difference?
2. As I understand it, the reference count on `a` is so high because there is already an object holding an integer value of `3` at the time I bound the name `a` to it. How does Python keep track of which object is holding `3` so that it binds the name `a` to it and increments its reference count accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

1. `gc.get_referrers` only returns objects the cycle-detecting GC knows about. Objects that couldn't possibly be involved in a reference cycle don't need to be tracked by the cycle detector, so they might not show up in the `get_referrers` list.
2. With [this array here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/intobject.c#l79):

   ```
   static PyIntObject *small_ints[NSMALLNEGINTS + NSMALLPOSINTS];
   ```