# Is there a magic method run when an object reference count is changed in Python

Tags: python

I want to a method that runs when object reference count is changed. is there a method like the following code ?

```
class Foo():
    def __method__(self):
        print("ojbect reference count is changed !")

a = Foo()
b = a  # runs __method__ because the reference count is increased
c = b  # runs __method__ because the reference count is increased
del b  # runs __method__ because the reference count is decreased
del c  # runs __method__ because the reference count is decreased
```

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the current ref count of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510406/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-current-ref-count-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: ^ It isn't really one though

Comment: and how do you intend to use such function if there is one ? what is the problem you trying to solve ?

Comment: @fins, I want to delete an object when reference count number of it changed to one or two or any other number.

Comment: wanting to delete an object once it's reference count change. any python object or a specific one ?

Comment: Calling the method would, itself, change the object's reference count.