# await for dying of weakref

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, weak-references

This might not be a good idea, but can I have `await` waiting for "dying" of `weakref`?

Especially, I want to do something like this

```py
from asyncio import losing_ref, wait, create_task
from weakref import ref

async def consumer(queue_ref):
    while queue_ref() is not None:
        await wait(losing_ref(queue_ref), queue_ref().get())
        ...
        
async def producer(queue):
    for i in range(20):
        await queue.put(i)
        
async def main():
    queue = Queue(1)
    create_task(sender(queue))
    create_task(receiver(ref(queue)))
    del queue // make sure `main` is not referencing to it
    ...
```

The point is like the `queue` can "close" itself without need of manual notification to the other end, since all reference to it is gone. This would be handy especially when used in a loop where you might have to raise `StopAsyncIteration` on the producer side manually

Comment: An interesting idea even if I find it a bad design. I would never rely on what the garbage collector does and mainly when it does. Anyway, waiting in `queue.get` will keep the reference alive. Maybe it could work with timeouts and checks between the `queue.get`s. BTW, there was a question about monitoring the regular reference count, but it is unanswered (https://stackoverflow.com/q/47254130/5378816).

Comment: I don't think this can work as suggested because the `wait(...)` invocation sends a *strong* reference to the queue to `wait()`, it being embedded in the bound method obtained with `queue_ref().get()`. You could instead emit an event when the producer goes away, and await that event and `queue.get()` using `wait(..., FIRST_COMPLETED)`. Then you can check the producer count and bail out if there are no more producers.