# Python: Magic method for when the object's reference count changes?

Tags: python, oop, python-datamodel

I want to a method that runs when object reference count is changed. is there a method like the following code ?

```py
class Foo():
    def __method__(self):
        print("ojbect reference count is changed !")

a = Foo()
b = a  # runs __method__ because the reference count is increased
c = b  # runs __method__ because the reference count is increased
del b  # runs __method__ because the reference count is decreased
del c  # runs __method__ because the reference count is decreased
```

Note: This is a repost of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254130/is-there-a-magic-method-run-when-an-object-reference-count-is-changed-in-python) question, I'm looking for an answer compatible with Python 3.10.

Thanks!

---

The reference count of my object never goes below 1. Taking this as a given, I tried to implement some clean-up code for when an object is dereferenced by all user-facing code by adding `__del__`. That didn't work, because there's one reference left.

So, I need to add some clean-up code for the reference count hits 1.

This is an XY Problem, and I'm comfortable with that. My actual situation involves singletons, wherein `((User("my_name") == User("my_name")) and (User("my_name") != User("other_name"))) is True`. To do this, there's an internally referenced dictionary that's handling all this. That's why the minimum reference count for an object is 1.

When an object is removed from the User's code, ie, the reference count reaches 1, I'd like to clean it up from my reference dictionary as well.

Comment: Why don't you use a weak reference for the internal reference to the object? So it will be deleted when all the user-facing code drops its references.

Comment: Don't you mean `is` instead of `==`?

Comment: Calling this method would, itself, change the object's reference count. Just about anything you do with the object inside the method would change the reference count too.

Comment: Even if you found a way to detect that there is only one reference left, there would be no way to delete the object. _"This is an XY Problem, and I'm comfortable with that"_ - well you should not be comfortable with that. You should ask the right question rather than the wrong question, especially if you know which one is right.

Comment: @zvone You're right, considering the accepted answer. I didn't want to change my singleton implementation, but I assume it would've been easier to answer if I focused the question more on it. Thanks

Comment: To me, this reads like a question written by someone who wants weak references, but doesn't know about weak references. The short answer to the original question is "no", but by providing a concrete use case it was possible to suggest a useful alternative approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no magic method like that in Python. However, if you're looking to implement a singleton with auto-cleanup, using a `WeakValueDictionary` would work:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from threading import Lock
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary

_USERS_LOCK = Lock()
_USERS: WeakValueDictionary[str, User] = WeakValueDictionary()


class User:
    def __new__(self, name: str) -> User:
        with _USERS_LOCK:
            # Try to return an existing user.
            try:
                user = _USERS[name]
            except KeyError:
                # Create and cache a new user.
                user = _USERS[name] = object.__new__(User)
                user.name = name
            # All done!
            return user
```

You can test this works as expected like so:

```
# Users created with a unique username return new user objects.
user1 = User("Dave")
assert user1.name == "Dave"
user2 = User("TheOnlyWayUp")
assert user2.name == "TheOnlyWayUp"
assert user1 is not user2

# The users are cached.
assert len(_USERS) == 2

# Users created with the same username as an existing user return
# the same user instance.
user3 = User("Dave")
assert user3 is user1

# The number of cached users remains the same.
assert len(_USERS) == 2

# Deleting the users frees up the cache.
del user1, user2, user3
assert len(_USERS) == 0
```

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

Comment: Why use a lock?

Comment: @KellyBundy: To prevent cases where two threads see a missing entry and both threads try to populate it.

Comment: @user2357112 So it's only needed if you have multiple threads, right? (And I see no indication of that in the question.)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, and for including the locking code :)

Comment: I included the lock to guard against multithreaded access to the cache. It's very low overhead, and avoids surprises in future. It can be taken out if the singleton cache doesn't have to *strictly* return singletons, or you can guarantee no multithreaded access.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to a method that runs when object reference count is changed. is there a method like the following code ?

No. Not only would it be a performance nightmare, it would be a footgun wrapped in caltrops. `__del__` already has a bunch of tricky and error prone edge cases, this would be a lot worse.

> To do this, there's an internally referenced dictionary that's handling all this.

Use weakrefs?

Comment: How would weakrefs help here?

Comment: You can use a WeakValueDictionary as a registry for your singletons. If an other instance of the singleton exists, you'll find it by looking up based on whatever identity keys, if all existing instances disappear, the entry will be collected. You can also do this by hand by maintaining a registry of actual weakref.ref and cleaning up dead entries yourself, if you need more exotic semantics.