# How to determine how many variables are referring the same id in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

consider the python code below

```
divyansh = 22
jhon = 22
# below are id's
id(divyansh)
id(jhon)
id(22)
# all of the above ids will be same
```

now i wish to find the names of the variables referring this particular id. |OR| The number of the variables reffing this particular id.

is there any way of doing this in python

Comment: This question could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510406/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-current-ref-count-of-an-object-in-python